# Inserting Dynamic Values Inside a Multiple date picker

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker

Iam using **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7zj/#update)** multiple date picker. I want to add dates dynamically into this text box.But it is not showing inside the text box. Jsfiddle added.

`<input type="text" id="from-input" value="02/20/2014">`

My php code is like below

```
<?php
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
?>
        <input type="text" id="from-input" value="<?php echo $fetch['sel_date']; ?>">
<?php
    }
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7zj/#update

[image]

Comment: It's working for me with Chrome

Comment: No value="02/20/2014" not showing by default.

Comment: I thought you were talking about after you clicked on the dates they weren't populating the input. Perhaps you should make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: My problem is when i set value of textbox with 02/20/2014, it is not showing on the textbox while executing the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First, you can't just add a value to the element you add `multiDatesPicker` to and expect that date to be selected because it will clear the values. Instead, use an alternate field, like this:

```
<div class="box">
<input type="text" id="from-input">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="orig-dates" value="<?php echo $fetch['sel_date']; ?>">
```

Then in your JS, you first create the datepicker, then add the dates to it:

```
$('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
var orig_dates_str = $("#orig-dates").val();
    if (orig_dates_str.length > 0) {
        var orig_dates_arr = orig_dates_str.split(",");
        var dates = new Array();
        for (i=0; i<orig_dates_arr.length; i++) {
            numbers = orig_dates_arr[i].split("-");
            d = new Date(numbers[0], numbers[1] - 1, numbers[2]);

            dates.push(d);
        }
        $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker('addDates', dates);
    }
```

Then your second error is that the format "MM/DD/YYYY" is not recognized. Instead, you need to do "YYYY-MM-DD".

In PHP you can do this like so:

```
$date = new DateTime($fetch['sel_date']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Put this into the <input>
```

[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7zj/1/)

Comment: I also want to show 2014-02-20 inside the from-input text box. Thanks @Mike

Comment: You have to put it there then. `$('#from-input').val(orig_dates_str);`. [[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7zj/2/)]